# Socket-io dynamic initialization

Tags: node.js, typescript, socket.io, angular5

### Problem statement

After implementing socket.io on my Angular app I was curious to learn if I could dynamically set-up the "SocketIoModule" on the client (FrontEnd) app.module file.

I would like load the URL and port from the server (Back-end) config file following the description of the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io)

```
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { SocketService } from './services/socket.service';
const socketConfig: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:3000', options: {} };

@NgModule({

[..]

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(socketConfig)
  ],
providers: [
  // all other providers
  <SocketProvider>
]

[..]
```

//package.json

```
   "ngx-socket-io": "^2.1.1",
   "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
   "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0"
```

#### Desired end state

```
//backend config service
let url = config.env.url.base + config.env.url.socketIoPort;
const socketConfig: SocketIoConfig = { url: url, options: {} };
```

As a side note, the main challenge is that when the client is loading, the UI doesn't have access to the server side (Angular security).

I also read that the best way to achieving this, is using the "environment/environments" files [Dev, Staging, Prod].

Final notes: the whole point of this is to have a centralized file to have all the configurations and make it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the client to dynamically get the socket.io config information from the server, you have to either include the config information in Javascript variables in a `<script>` tag in the HTML file that the client is running from OR you have to have a known URL that the client can send an Ajax call to request the socket.io config info.

The first could be part of a server-side template system that includes a script tag that defines a Javascript object containing socket.io config info in every page on the site so the socket.io config info is always available.  That server-side template system could get the data from your one central place in the server.

The second could just set up an Ajax reachable route at a known URL that the client can fetch the config info as needed.  This is probably slower than the first option because it involves a separate round-trip to the server, but is perhaps less of an imposition on the site architecture because it doesn't have to affection generation of HTML files on the site, it's just Javascript that goes with your socket.io initialization code.  On the server, it's just an additional route to add that's independent of everything else.

Comment: This is excellent solution and the one who fits my problem. However, as a side note, my team (after a long discussion) decided to put the socket.io server in the same port as the app server.

Comment: @Cabrra - Yes, putting it on the same port is the easiest for the client.

Comment: I'm in same situation now, I need some more clarification on this. How to get const socketConfig: SocketIoConfig = { url: serverURL, options: {} }; serverURL from my API. Is this possible to call service and get url and port from my php server

Comment: @VinothKumar - Please read the first paragraph of the answer above.  It applies to your situation too.

Comment: Yes I have read this paragraph, I have the code in ionic 3, For this only struggling where to add this script tag in this. Do you have any idea on this where I have to update the script tag code in ionic3?

Comment: @VinothKumar - If you need more help that this answer offers, I'd suggest you post your own question with your actual code and tag it appropriately to attract people that know your environment.  I don't know anything about ionic3 so this question isn't a good place to get help.

Comment: Okay thanks for your response, will update as a new question